# backbone js - reduce calls to the server

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Just wondering how people deal stopping multiple external server calls? I'm doing everything in the .complete of the fetch because otherwise when I try to call anything the fetch hasn't completed and nothing is populated in the collection.

I'm new to backbone so I'm probably missing a trick.. but is there a way to do a fetch and store that information somewhere so that you never have to fetch again, you just work off the collection as a variable? All of my information comes from an external site, so I don't want to be making lots of unnecessary external calls if I can. I'm not updating the server or anything, its all just read-only.

What do other people do for a similar set up? Am I missing something silly? Or am I set up badly for this? Here's what I have so far (work in progress)

Oh also: I'm doing the fetch in the router.. is that a bad idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/leapin_leprechaun/b8y6L0rf/

```
.complete(
    //after the fetch has been completed
    function(){
        //create the initial buttons
        //pull the unique leagues out
        var uniqueLeagues = _.uniq(matches.pluck("league"));

        //pull the unique leagues out   
        var uniqueDates = _.uniq(matches.pluck("matchDate"));

        //pass to info to the relative functions to create buttons   
        getLeagues(uniqueLeagues);
        getMatchDates(uniqueDates);
        homeBtn();
        fetched = true;
    }
); //end complete
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Avoiding multiple external servers access and how to handle async functions are totally different thing.what's your point?

Comment: yea fair enough, maybe what I'm struggling with is handling async functions then. If I could work properly with async then I wouldn't have to have multiple calls. I guess the crux of it is how can I make 1 async call and store that data in a collection that I can work with without having to be within the .complete

Comment: Actually.. do I even need to be async if I'm just doing a read only to kick it off? Could I just do async:false on my fetch instead??

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need an event driven approach which you don't seem to be familiar with - yet. I'll take the time to answer with some schemes, if it helps you.

Comment: that'd be much appreciated!! Or even if you don't have time then just have some good links that I can read up on more myself would be fantastic. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an often recurring question but the answer is rather simple.
Perhaps I'll make some drawings today, if it helps.
I never took the time to learn UML properly, so forgive me for that.

**1. The problem**

What you currently have is this:

[image]

The problem however is that this isn't very dynamic.
If these 3 functions at the right would require to be executed from different ajax callback functions, they need to be added to any of these callbacks.
Imagine that you want to change the name of any of these 3 functions, it means that your code would break instantly, and you would need to update each of these callbacks.

Your question indicates that you feel that you want to avoid every function to perform the async call separately, which is indeed the case because this creates unnecessary overhead.

**2. Event aggregation**

The solutions is to implement an event driven approach, which works like this:

[image]

This pattern is also called pub/sub (or observer pattern) because there are objects that publish events (in this case on the left) and objects that subscribe (on the right).
With this pattern, you don't need to call every function explicitly after the ajax callback is finished; rather, the objects subscribe to certain events, and execute methods when the event gets triggered. This way you are always certain that the methods will be executed.
Note that when triggering an event, parameters can be passed as well, which allows you to access the collection from the subscribing objects.

**3. Backbone implementation**

Backbone promotes an event driven approach.
Setting up an event aggregator is simple and can be done as follows:

```
window.APP = {};
APP.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

From the ajax callback, you just trigger an event (you give it any name you want, but by convention, a semi colon is used as a separator):

```
APP.vent.trigger("some:event", collection);
```

The three receiving objects subscribe to the event as follows:

```
APP.vent.on("some:event", function(collection){ 
    console.log(collection.toJSON()); 
});
```

And that's basically all.
One thing to take into account is to make sure that when you subscribe to events using "on", you also need to un-subscribe by calling "off", if you no longer need the object.

Comment: wow.. thank you so much for taking the time to do this. Can I just clarify something if you don't mind. You say that "the functions subscribe to certain events, and execute methods when the event gets triggered." - are you talking about clicks etc at this point? Or for example is there like a 'collection is populated' event?

Comment: pubsub might not help here.pubsub is used in a case something like if you want one view trigger updates in other views which aint the view's child view.and the question is if it's able to ensure the models are fetched when he use them or not

Comment: @leapin_leprechaun No, I mean custom events that you can set up yourself as explained in part 3 of the answer. The objects on the right can be any kind of objects; for example backbone view objects, or custom objects that you create yourself with plain Javascript. That doesn't exclude of course, that these view objects can still react on events triggered by the DOM (such as click events).

Comment: oh ok, I get ya now! Brilliant.. thanks so much for this

Comment: @suish I'm not sure what you mean. This ensures that the models are fetched, and allows the other functions to only execute when the models are definitely fetched.

Answer (score 1):

How to handle that is all up to you in Backbone.js but here is one of options you can take

Creating a View which has body as its el and handle everything.(I usually use Coffee so This might has some syntax errors)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  mainView = new MainView({el: "body"});
});

MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize : function(){
    this.prepareCollection();
  },
  prepareCollection : function(collection){
    _checker = function(){
      if (collection.length === _done) {
        this.render();
      }
    };
    _.bind(_checker,this);
    collection.each(function(item){
      item.fetch(
        success : function(){
          //you can also initialize router here.
          _checker();
        }
      );
    });
  },
  rener : function(){
    //make instance of View whichever you want and you can use colleciton just like variable
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks for this. Yea I don't think I'm taking advantage of initialize at all at the moment really, I'll definitely look more into that. Also wasn't sure of the el: "body" part so that's great too - thanks for this