# in Backbone.Marionette is there a way to call an collectionView's method from outside?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

i want to bind some functions from a collectionView to buttons outside of it
let's say i have something like:

```
someScope(){
  MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    theFunction: function(){...},
    ...
  });
  view = new MyView();
  //render and stuff
}
someOtherScope(){
  call to theFunction
}
```

is there a way like MyApp.regions.regionOfMyView.trigger.. ?
do i have to save view as a global variable for that?

Comment: Check the scheme I've made in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755976/backbone-js-reduce-calls-to-the-server/27756807#27756807

Comment: Yes, use events. It gives you a looser coupling than using globals.

Comment: @KimGysen, thanks for your comment. that really helped. i looked that up and this article [link](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/21/backbone-event-best-practices/) has also a good explanation.